# drawing a bitmap with bitmapdata(with matrix) in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to draw my stage as a new bitmap.
How can I cut the top bar of the stage (height of my top bar is 100 pixels) and draw it as a new bitmap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do this by adding everything you want in the bitmap to a sprite and then you do this:

```
var stageSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(stageSprite);

//Creates the sprite you want to draw

stageSprite.addChild(objectsYouWantToDraw);

//Here you add the objects you want to draw to the sprite

var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(stage.stageWidth, 100, true, 0);
var bit:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd);
addChild(bit);

//Create a bitmap with your size

bmd.draw(stageSprite);

//Draw the objects to a bitmap
```

You could optionally add a matrix if you want to get another portion of the screen.

```
var m:Matrix = new Matrix();
m.translate(-xOffset, -yOffset);
bmd.draw(stageSprite, m);

//Draw the objects to a bitmap with the offsets you want
```

Comment: ahm okay i built it in another way. Anyway thanks for answering.